# How to find between tenth with twentieth data with MagicalRecord

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord

If my table in database which has 100 data. I want to find between tenth with twentieth. I want to know how to find them with MagicalRecord, or sqlite statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget Magical Record and use native Core Data.

```
fetchRequest.fetchOffset = 10;
fetchRequest.fetchLimit  = 10;
```

Comment: HA HA ! Thanks! But I used it everywhere. I will cry!

Comment: Get a hanky and tick the checkmark above.

Comment: En, it's a good idea! First , I need to get my girlfriend back otherwise just tissue for me!

Comment: Magicalrecord gives you access to the fetch requests. Look at the docs, all is explained there.

Comment: en, I create a custom fetch request an use MR_...excuteFetch....